# Correct syntax for Apache Virtual Hosts on Windows?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2, windows-xp

I apologize, but this is difficult to figure out.

I am running Apache 2.2, this is on a Windows box, my own home PC for development use only. Windows XP Pro SP3.

I have five sites that I need to create virtual hosts for. Each has the same URL but different IP addresses and different folders.

I have the URL + port pointing to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, but can't get the syntax correct for the virtual hosts.

```
<VirtualHost site.local:1>
DocumentRoot "C:/www/1"
ServerName site.local:1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost site.local:2>
DocumentRoot "C:/www/2"
ServerName site.local:2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost site.local:3>
DocumentRoot "C:/www/3"
ServerName site.local:3
</VirtualHost>
```

And no, these are not real ports I plan to use, just to give you a basic example of the folder structure and URL structure.

I put a standard index.html in one of the folders and then I try to go to that URL and it always times out.

So I want to know the correct syntax and how to do this in the future, because this part seems to be always confusing.

Comment: You have not included enough information to help you: Are there any errors in your Apache log files?

Comment: Why are you using different ports ?

Comment: Just the way the client requested. Not my preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have VirtualHosts with the same `ServerName` but on different ports, you're after the following Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:1111>
    ServerName site.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:2222>
    ServerName site.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/2"
</VirtualHost>

# etc
```

and you only need:

```
127.0.0.1    site.local
```

in your hosts-file.

Comment: They are the same ip, same url, different ports.

Comment: Your question says "Each has the same url, but different ip addresses"; I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment on the original question -- Log entries would be extremely helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Also as a wild shot in the dark, please make sure that you have [`Listen`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directives for each port you want to use in your Apache configuration.